# Kendo Grid doesn't handle dirty item for me. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid (inline mode) in my mvc project and I initialized the grid all by mvc.
The problem is when I add a new row it gets a 0 id and it's dirty property is set to true.
How can I refresh the added item and set the correct id to it?

This is my Kendo Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<IranHost.Tools.Services.Core.DataModel.Site>()
                                    .Name("grid")
                                    .Columns(columns =>
                                    {
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.Domain).Width(250).Title("دامین");
                                        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text("ویرایش").UpdateText("ذخیره").CancelText("لغو"); command.Destroy().Text("حذف"); });
                                    })
                                    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("افزودن دامین جدید").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "add-button" }))
                                    .Editable(editable => { editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine); })
                                    .Sortable()
                                    .Pageable()
                                    .Scrollable()
                                    .Events(action => { action.Edit("gridEdit"); action.Save("gridSave"); action.SaveChanges("gridSaveChanges"); })
                                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                        .Ajax()
                                        .Events(events => { events.Error("result_handler"); })
                                        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                                        .Create(create => create.Action("AddDomain", "Service", new { customerID = ViewBag.CustomerId }))
                                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetDomainListForGrid", "Service", new { customerID = ViewBag.CustomerId }))
                                        .Update(update => update.Action("EditDomain", "Service"))
                                        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteDomain", "Service"))
                                    )
                                    )
```

And This is what I've done in the server side:

```
public ActionResult AddDomain([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, DataModel.Site site)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var pattern = "([\\da-z\\.-]+)\\.([a-z\\.]{2,6})([\\/\\w\\.-]*)";
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(site.Domain, pattern))
            {
                //TODO: Must be added in the framework.
                ModelState.AddModelError("ERROR", "Wrong URL Format!");
                return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            var siteContext = new Biz.Site(DataContext);
            siteContext.Add(site);
            DataContext.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.AddModelError("ADDED", site.id);
            return Json(new[] { site }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(403);
    }
```

But still it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!
I was using older version of KendoUI and it didn't have requestEnd so I started using AddModelError to handle server side results.
Actually I used AddModelError not for error but just telling the client side that adding/editing the item was with success.

It was actually a very bad idea but I didn't have a choice at moment. In the client side I was raising Events.Error("result_handler"). Kendo though that it really is an error so it didn't made any changes on the ui but setting the dirty property to true!

Now my boss is trying to get new version of KendoUI in the meanwile I'm using ajaxComplete to raise other events. Unfortunately I don't really have much of a choice until I get the newer version!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.  Now that I see your server side code, it does look pretty dubious.  What you might try, since you are in a pinch, is add an extra field to your model, put your success message in this field.  Alway check this field when a view loads and notify the user (via kendo pop-up window is nice).  I do this to pass errors to the page in situtations where I don't have a ModelState to work with.  If you did something like that you would be able to notify your user that it was 'ADDED' without corrupting the ModelState the way you are.  And why the site.Domain = site.Domain?

Comment: :D site.Domain = site.Domain!
Actually it's removed after editing this post. It was one of the things that left out there out of no where! :D

Answer (score 0):

The default int id value is 0 when you create new record.

The idea is when you hit the save button that record is send to server where you need to return the item with the updated id (the one retrieved from the database). Then back on the client when the Grid read that value and see that it is different from the default one (zero) it will mark the new record as successfully inserted.
If there is no item returned or the updated id value is missing the Grid will continue to mark the record as dirty and it will continue to resend it to the server on future save/saveChanges  button clicks.

If you want to change the default ID value you can use the DefaultValue method over inside the model definition.

```
.Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id).DefaultValue(-42))
```

Comment: Yeah, I know the process must be like that. but the problem is I don't know how to get the proper result. As you see I added extra information to the bottom of my question. Please read that and tell me your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the record back to the grid after any CRUD operation.  You even want to do this on Destory to return an error for your error_handler event. This is code I use on a number of answers I have posted here, there is some extra stuff, but what you should be looking at is how the single record is converted to a List just like the initial Read.  Look at my other answers for more details on the model and the FlattenToThis if needed.  But I think this should be enough to get you where you are going.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreatePerson([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            person = _personDataProvider.Create(person);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, e.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }
    var persons = new List<Person> {person};
    DataSourceResult result = PersonModel.FlattenToThis(persons).ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult ReadPeople([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var persons = _personDataProvider.Read(false);
    DataSourceResult result = PersonModel.FlattenToThis(persons).ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdatePerson([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            person = _personDataProvider.Update(person);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, e.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }
    var persons = new List<Person>() {person};
    DataSourceResult result = PersonModel.FlattenToThis(persons).ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DestroyPerson([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            person = _personDataProvider.Destroy(person);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "There was an error deleting this record, it may still be in use.");
        }
    }
    var persons = new List<Person>() {person};
    DataSourceResult result = PersonModel.FlattenToThis(persons).ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I have added the serverside part of my code to my original question. Please look at that and tell me your opinion.